# Populate 2nd dropdown based on results of 1st

Tags: php, jquery

At the moment I using a dynamic select to populate a dropdown. What I would like to do is display a 2nd dropdown with results based on the selection of the first. I have no idea how to go about this and have searched for an answer but to no avail. I have included the code I using to populate the first menu, and if you need any further code, please let me know. I am quite willing to look at jQuery or javascript if someone could help with the code. Many thanks

```
<form id="boxform" method="post" class="webform" name="boxform" />

        <label for="company">Select a Company:</label>
                <select name="company" id="company" />
                    <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select a Company</option>
                        <?php
                          do {  
                        ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?>"><?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?></option>
                        <?php

                    } 
                        while ($row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust));
                        $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetcust);

                if($rows > 0)

                    {
                        mysql_data_seek($Recordsetcust, 0);
                        $row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust);
                    }

                         ?>
                 </select>
```

UPDATE:

This is the code for the 2nd dropdown in php format that I have at the moment if it would help move on with this, thanks

```
<label for="boxrtnaddress">Select Address</label>
     <select name="boxrtnaddress" id="boxrtvaddress" />
        <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select Delivery Address</option>

            <?php
            while ($row_rs_select_address2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_select_address2))
            {  
                    $value=$row_rs_select_address2['address1_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['address2_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['address3_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['town_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['postcode_com'];
                    $caption=$row_rs_select_address2['address1_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['address2_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['address3_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['town_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['postcode_com'];
                    echo "<option value=\"", $value, "\">", $caption, "</option>";
            }
            ?>
    </select>
```

+++++++++++++SOLUTION++++++++++

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
            $("#company").change(function() {
              if ($(this).val()!="") $.get("getOptions.php?customer=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
                $("#divId").html(data);
                });
              });
      });
</script>
```

getOptions.php

```
<?php
    $customer = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET["customer"] ); // not used here, it's the customer choosen

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = "sample";
      if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($db, $con);
        $query_rs_select_address2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM company_com where idcode_com = '$customer'");
        $rs_select_address2 = mysql_query($query_rs_select_address2, $con) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rs_select_address2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_select_address2);
        $totalRows_rs_select_address2 = mysql_num_rows($rs_select_address2);



                    $address=$row_rs_select_address2['address1_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['address2_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['address3_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['town_com']. " ". $row_rs_select_address2['postcode_com'];
                     echo '<select name="customer">'.'<option value="">Select delivery address</option>'.'<option value="address">'.$address.'</option>'.'</select>';



?>
```

Comment: by set a name for the selection make a sub button then call `ifisset('sub',$_POST)` by `$_POST[the option that was selected]` you can continue

Comment: @negin sorry I do not understand. can you show example?

Comment: @bollo what do you mean by $("#divId").html(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may help, here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gZzQr/

that dynamically appends a `select` based on the selection of first `select` the code is messy and dirty so im not gonna post it here :)

you can have a look at the following to better understand the working

[`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) triggers when the selected value of a `select` is changed

`is(':empty')` checks whether the div to which the newly created `select
 is to be appended **is** empty or not

http://api.jquery.com/is/

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

**Edit**
i'll give you hints hopefully you'll fill in the rest of code...

first of all what you need to do is handle the `change` event of your first drop down and when the value changes you can do an `ajax`, `get`, `post` request to your server, fetch the results and populate the second drop down, here is a useful stackoverflow link that may help you

[php dropdown menu population](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522227/php-dropdown-menu-population)

```
$("#firstDD").change(function(){
var value = $(this).val();//get the changed value of first dd(drop down)


//now do a post request 

$.post("results.php",{data:value},function(data){
//get the values here and populate the second drop down

});

});
```

in your results.php

get the value from first drop down

```
$val = $_POST['data'];
//now do the sql queries to fetch desired result
//and echo the results back

echo $results ;
```

here are some useful links

http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/08/15/jquery-json-with-php-json_encode-and-json_decode/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php

Comment: how would I convert that code to pull from menu from mysql? thanks

Comment: you want to populate the second drop down with values from mysql db  ?

Comment: thank you. I shall try to make it work. Th only question I have is re the php db call. Is there an example of how to do that or is it the same as standard php?

Comment: just the normal way you access the db and make queries

Comment: posted solution that suits me. just need to get the while loop working in php. Might help someone. Thanks for all your help